# Merging with Partially Similar Columns in R

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to merge together two data-frames by matching their Tickers. However, in my first data-frame, some companies are listed with two tickers (as below)

```
Company               Ticker         Returns
1800-Flowers          FLWS, FWC        .01
First Busey Corp      BUSE             .02
First Bancshare Inc   FBSI              0
```

In the second data frame, there is only one ticker.

```
Ticker          Other Info
FLWS            50
BUSE            60
FBSI            20
```

How can I merge these two files together in R so that it will recognize that the data from FLWS belongs to the first row in data frame 1 because it contains the Ticker?

Please note that in data frame 1, most companies have only 1 ticker listed, many have 2, and some companies have 3 or 4 tickers.

Comment: Can you use `dput` to create a reproducible example ? Very hard to read your data.

Comment: Is there anything prevent you from separating the Company with multiple tickers into multiple rows? If not, you can use `separate_rows` in `tidyr` to separate them into rows and do the merge after.

Comment: What if you have ticker in dataframe1 like `FLWS,BUSE`? In this case , what other info do you expect?